# Would feudalism work in a post-industrial society?

Tags: economy, post-apocalypse, industrial-age, royalty, feudalism

In my world, World War 3 happens and most countries are devastated. Nuclear weapons are used and there is widespread anarchy in many places. Some countries are untouched but many countries completely collapse and other nations are reduced to a 19th Century or even 18th Century technology level.

I was wondering if feudalism could make a comeback in a world that still has limited modern knowledge and technology. By feudalism, I mean there would be a king that nobles would swear fealty to. These nobles would own farmlands that serfs would work on. And the nobles would receive produce from the serfs in exchange for military protection from bandits and other nobles.

On one hand, there is no particular technology that obsoletes feudalism. On the other hand, there is probably a good reason that no modern-day country uses feudalism as a socioeconomic or political system. Could feudalism be feasible in a decentralized semi-modern country in an unstable world? Or does the Industrial Revolution or certain modern ideas condemn feudalism to the history books?

Comment: The answer is going to be highly dependent upon the specifics of your world and their specific society that you haven't laid out in the question above. Remember you're building a fictional world with different history and cultures to our own.

Comment: The word [postindustrial](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/postindustrial) does not mean what you think it means. (And what obsoletes feudalism is money. Feudalism is what you get when you do not have a functional monetary economy. As soon as human society develops enough so that trade beyond the boundaries of the village becomes easy, feudalism is dead.) (And you have it in your description: *"these nobles would own farmlands that serfs would work on"*, meaning nobody has any money.) (BTW, the entire point of feudalism is that the nobles do not *own* the lands; they *hold* them from the king.)

Comment: Why wouldn't it? .. What about feudalism and industrialisation do you even think could be potentially mutually exclusive? If the answer is nothing then why ask this question? .. the reason there are no major feudal countries these days is simply due to survival of the fittest, democracies of some form are just more stable forms of government because they inherently allow for non violent regime change within their structure (we call them elections ) so that the structure itself isn't disrupted when regime change happens, a feudal or monarchy has to collapse for regime change to occur.

Comment: I would recommend https://[acoup.blog crusader kings series of articles, part iib in particular. There there is some explanation of why vassalage and manorialism.  Short answer: if depends on the existing/surviving social institutions.

Comment: This question fits the "How much wood could a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?" category.

Comment: @
Pelinore
 Non-violent transition  of power? Please explain Trump. Oh, and on paper  and in their constitution, Russia is a 'democracy' with 'elections'.

Comment: The Treaty (Peace) of Westphalia is what made feudalism obsolete. The concept of the sovereign state, wherein the government rules all.

Comment: Please elaborate on the difference between feudalism and an oligarchy. One is in an agrarian economy, the other is in an industrial economy, but both envelop the same principle.

Comment: @AlexP you said that "As soon as human society develops enough so that trade beyond the boundaries of the village becomes easy, feudalism is dead". Could you give your reasoning about this?

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond What about Trump? Please  explain for me precisely what form of clinical delusion could possibly allow anyone to compare any minor protests that might have occured during the transition of power from Trump to Biden to something like either the French or Russian revolutions and think for one second that they actually had a serious point to make  were millions killed? hundreds of thousands perhaps? was there an actual civil war as Trump's supporters tried to retain power for him by force of arms that I didn't hear of? or was Biden able to just take office.

Comment: @
Pelinore
 The complete and total oblivion of any pretense to the neutrality of the Supreme Court, and the complete denial of any pretense to the Supreme Court being constrained by the constitution. Oh, and add to that the almost daily mass killings that totally dominate American society. They are a product of (symptom of?) the Westocratic system of adversarial governance under a winner-take-all loser-gets-nothing approach.

Comment: Define 'works,' because neo-feudalism would be incredibly bad for everyone who isn't rich, and actively destroy that society's ability to improve lives, but the system would be very stable and self-sustaining until someone comes in from outside with an absolutely enormous/extremely capable army fanatically devoted to their collective success and proves why you invest in your common people all over again.

Comment: @atrefeu: Because as soon as trade beyond the boundaries of the village revives, land stops being the only form of wealth, and quite quickly becomes a secondary and unimportant form of wealth.

Comment: @Nous the Space Alien
 There is no credible evidence that feudalism is any more or less advantageous to the standard of living and 'human livability rights' of the lower economic common residents than is Westocracy. Under both systems, the common folk (the bulk of the residents) are, at best, just surviving.

Comment: Trade beyond the borders can operate under feudalism - as long as all the trade is done by the ruler / under the control of the ruler. Early trading seems to have been done that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Feudalism could make a comeback only if the population and level of technology declined so much that the majority of people would be working in farming. Merchants, traders and skilled craftspeople are much harder to control than peasants who are bound to their land; if people in bourgeois professions don't like the local regime, they take their business elsewhere. Industrial workers can also easily switch between jobs. Feudalism becomes impossible or at least impractical and unlikely when industry and business become a major part of the economy, generating more income than farming. Central government is then needed to impose the same laws and rules everywhere.

Adoption of democracy is also related to the rise of the middle class. To keep the wealthy middle class happy, it must be given some influence in how the country or other jurisdiction is governed, thus some kind of democracy usually appears.

Comment: It was the rise of the business sector and the concentration of population in cities that put an end to feudalism. Merchants in the cities bore no loyalties to any fiefdom lord. Instead of owning land for farming and hunting, the urban merchants and urban barons owned the land for renting to urban workers.

Comment: Democracy has nothing to do with the 'middle class', unless you are totally prepared to accept that China is a full fledged democracy.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond I wrote 'usually', because there are notable exceptions. Actually I wouldn't declare China an exception yet, because industrialization is a quite recent development there. Only a few decades - one generation - ago most of the population were still farm workers. Fundamental changes in society take time, and cultural differences also play a role.

Comment: @
Cloudberry
Yes, 6,000 years of contiguous, continuous culture and society based on the sanctity of the family and the honor of your ancestors has a lot to do with it. If one considers a 'religion' as an institution that defines and directs the moral, ethical, and social values system of a culture, (I am not convinced a religion needs a deity - that is a particularly quaint White-Western-Catholic-centric concept, many consider Humanism as a religion) then Confucianism is the world's longest surviving, prospering mainstream religion, at least three, maybe four times older than Christianity.

Comment: China had a prospering 'middle class' hundreds of centuries before Europe was an economic consideration. It was European colonialism and imperialism that wiped it out.

Answer (score 4):

The effectiveness and efficiency of feudalism is not directly related to 'industrialization' or the level of technology per say. The fall of feudalism was a direct result of the rise of urban centers and cities, and the rise of the merchant sector and industrialists. Merchants and craftsmen had no loyalties to any local fiefdom. Their domain was the urban setting, where land ownership followed a distinctly different paradigm. (However, it can be argued that industrialization and technological advancement was what created the urban environment and the rise of merchants, industrialists, and craftsmen in the first place.)

The urban landowners made their wealth from renting to workers and laborers, who worked and labored for entities unrelated to the landowners. The residents of tenements were not employed by their landlords, in the same manner as peasants were 'employed' by feudal lords. ('Contracted' rather than 'employed', there was no such thing as an 'employee' in the feudal system, no such term, in fact. The closest term to employee/employer was 'slave' or 'servant'. In point of fact, a lot of what is referred to as 'slavery' or 'servitude' back then was what we call 'paid employment' today - there was just no other term for it. The concept of 'employment' did not really arise until industrialization. Until industrialization, there was no concept of 'payment for a unit of labor time', only for 'specific services'.)

The feudal system can not work in an urban environment, unless the 'town' is a purely corporate town (all lands owned by the corporate entity/employer, not a generic landowner/landlord, and rented to the workers of that corporation). In point of fact, the corporate town is perhaps the closest example of a feudal system in an urban merchant/craftsman environment.

So to the extent that a corporate town can be considered a feudal system, then 'modified feudalism' could be possible in an industrialized urban setting.

Another point to be made, is that feudalism was a stateless system. That is, there were no defined state borders under feudalism. Sovereign states and statehood did not exist until after the Peace of Westphalia. (Germany did not become a 'state' as we understand it today until Kaiser Wilhelm, and the late 1800's early 1900's. Until then, it was a collection of locally-owned and governed 'kingdoms' with very limited 'state' oversight.) The only true borders were the borders of the estate or Fiefdom, and they were enforced by the power of the lords, not any legal or rules-based 'real estate' system. Under the feudal system, Kings ruled a collection of fiefdoms, not specific 'states', and were more cultural/social institutions rather than military/policing institutions. The Court was the center of socialization and diplomacy, the King a figurehead of the Court.

In order for there to be any official or formalized 'land title' or 'land ownership registration', there has to be some form of 'collective oversight' wherein the land ownership can be formally registered with. That was the purpose of the King's Court. It gave credence and credibility to land claims.

For your system to work, would require the demise of the modern 'sovereign state' concept, and the degeneration of statehood and state borders. This, of course, would be a byproduct/artifact of the general anarchy in a post-global-conflict society.

Answer (score 3):

**Feudalism and industry is *difficult*, not *impossible.***

The core of feudalism is that, *in theory*, the monarch owns most of the means of production and more-or-less permanently gives them to henchmen in return for personal loyalty and defined services. These henchmen then temporarily give part of their gift to their henchmen, all the way down to the serfs at the bottom.

- The 'means of production' are mostly agricultural land, but also the right to catch fish in some lake or river, the right to build a brige or mill, etc.
- In theory, the fief is given temporarily. In practice, the relationship is inheritable.
- Services are defined in the feudal 'contracts.' One fat pig by Michaelmas, two weeks labor during harvest (while the lord provides bread and beer on those days), etc. The serf could not switch to raising cotton, or work in a factory, because *a pig* is owed, not the value of the pig. This started to change at the end of the feudal period, but changing it was a drawn-out process due to the inheritable nature of the 'contracts.'
- Each level of nobility skims enough to live in the expected style. For a knight ruling over a few hamlets, this might not be much better than the living of the more prosperous farmers.
- Note that I used male pronouns for the historical case, because service usually included military service for a set number of weeks, to be performed by men. *Yes, there were a few exceptions. But overwhelmingly, we're talking about men.*

But in my first sentence, I talked about *personal loyalty and defined services.* The bullet points mostly talked about the *defined services* going up the chain, and ignores the principle of mutual loyalty, which was the theoretical underpinning of feudalism. Consider a more extreme form of [paternalistic conservativism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paternalistic_conservatism).

- Imagine a society where factory owners are expected to provide company housing, and company stores, and company schools, as a privilege and not as a means of further exploitation of the workforce. These services are part of the job contract, and quality is expected to be *better* than on the free market. Employees would be much more reluctant to change employers if that means they have to move housing, and that their children have to go to a different school.
- Imagine, and that is unusual for our view of feudalism or early industrialization, **that employees can only be fired for very good cause** involving employee misconduct. The employer is expected, by the legal system and by society, to provide pensions, to maintain employees during time of economic downturns, etc.
- Children of employees would go to the company school (see above) with the expectation of learning the company trade, and getting a job. There may be options to switch, but for practical purposes, most jobs are inheritable.
- Find a solution for families with different employers. Does one of them transfer? Does one of them become a homemaker? Do gender roles affect this?
- Imagine further that in business-to-business deals, the legal system holds the general contractor responsible for the details of the operation of a subcontractor. The response could either be to do things in-house, or do develop a stable, mutual trust relationship between general contractors and subcontractors.

Comment: (1) The legal system *does* hold the general contractor responsible for the performance of subcontractors. (2) What you are describing is more like [corporatism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporatism) (such as, for example, fascist Italy) than feudalism. (3) Large scale industrialization needs to have a large mass of free consumers who would buy the products made in the factories; otherwise you run into the unsolvable problems of running a large scale planned economy.

Comment: @AlexP, regarding responsibility, consider the debate in the West if companies are responsible for work conditions at subcontractors abroad (ban on prison labor, environmental conditions, etc.) Regarding corporatism, there are elements, but I stressed the inheritable nature of the society I described. Regarding free consumers, even communism worked after a fashion. Certainly better than feudalism ...

Comment: In the historical development of feudalism, it was the feudal overlord (landowner) that had total control and ownership over all the lands he owned, not any entity that was 'above' him. There were no state boundaries, only local estate boundaries, enforced by power. Over time, an over-riding 'state' governance system evolved to integrate these local fiefdoms, but there were still no state boundaries, only the boundaries of the collective fiefdoms. The 'king' derived all of his power and authority at the pleasure of the estate (fiefdom) owners, the 'King's Court' was cultural and social.

Comment: One notes this severely constrains development and innovation because work and ideas can't move freely

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond, the overlord was expected to grant fiefs to lesser nobles. Failing to do so would have broken the social contract. A king might be able to remove any one noble, but not all of them.

Answer (score 3):

Feudalism makes sense with weak central power that can't effectively tax directly its population and raise a standing army, so shifting this task and power to local elites is the way to go.

After having a nuclear war, I'd expect a huge ideological shift towards some form of hard core nationalism and militarism, which would naturally evolve in to de facto military dictatorship or in case of countries more used to democracy in to some form illiberal democracy. Fielding a few knights seems unimpressive for a total war.

Feudal like arrangement make only sense when:

- you actually field really small number of highly professional troops
- when you just started uniting your nation back and quite a few warlords were willing to join, but you had to guarantee them a high level of autonomy.

So the most realistic explanation would be having total collapse of state institutions, resurgence of de facto warlords and later reaching a compromise deal. But even under those conditions, one would expect more a patchwork state, where quite a few provinces have retained local democracy.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following ingredients to make Feudalism more believable:

- a very depopulated world
- loss of agricultural productivity.

**Loss of agricultural productivity**

You need loss of agricultural productivity *and* a tie-in to land for agricultural produce. More on that later.

You can have a loss of agricultural productivity by climate reasons. Or by loss of modern technologies, including any and all that make food supply ample. But low agricultural output and low productivity in general, even combined, do not require the foregoing of all post-industrial technologies and know-hows.

For example, say 90% of the remaining population on earth is required to produce sufficient food in aggregate. But a highly automated factory complex produce radios with few human input -- sure you always have upstream input but you can certainly have designs that suit simplified inputs. Said factory may be able to produce enough radios for 5% of the earth's population annually -- allowing some to always have new ones and the rest to only work with old radio sets that may become faulty in some way due to age. In this scenario, you could say a lot of technological advancement is included in the production of radio, so much so that very little input is enough to produce for the whole world. Yet overall productivity of the world is low because food is required and food is being a bottleneck for greater economical development.

Loss of agricultural productivity can be important for Feudalism. Feudalism was a land-based social order where

1. workers were tied to the same parcels of land all-year-long
2. nobles had the authority and ability to tax production from (larger) land parcels
3. a hierarchy existed to combine tax over large geographical areas and thus support things such as a military that can provide stability and order and some luxury items that helped people feel that the authority was deserved and proper.

If people can move around freely and still be a part of a productive process, then they won't be willing to stay under some abstract contract that bind them to some designated noble -- however relatively un-educated they may be.

So for the sake of Feudalism, you should tie 90%+ of earth's remaining population to daily working over the same pieces of land.

Note that low variability in agricultural productivity is also needed. ie. You shouldn't have a single place that is highly productive and nowhere else that can produce food. If the only place that can produce starch based food is in the UN headquarter building in a city named New York. You can have whatever social order that makes sense at UN. Outside of it, people are not tied with land anymore.

That said, a generally unproductive world but a few pockets of productivity -- even within agriculture -- can make for interesting dynamics. Like 0 everywhere vs 100 at one place wouldn't work. 1 vs 2 on the other hand could be interesting.

**A depopulated world**

A depopulated world does a number of things in Feudalism's favor, including:

- difficulty to maintain law and order over vast areas (and the consummate incentive to banditry)
- difficulty to maintain education
- even more difficulty with aggregate output that feeds into everything above
- the same sequence of events could have destroyed the social/national institutions in our real world in the same stroke

The implications are self-evident. Without the large population the modern earth has and supports, the historical benefits Feudalism was supposed to provide are not easily replaced via alternatives. They included social cohesion and stability of life. The key is to take away alternatives.

What loss of agricultural productivity achieves is that people are unable to move around and be productive other than being peasants of their specific pieces of land.
Depopulation takes away plausible alternatives by not permitting  individuals with free time. For 90%+ of population, you work your field for 8 hours a day or your starve. Otherwise, when people have free time, they will try to do things that break the current order. Say there is no difference between a republic where a government imposes tax and a monarchy where nobles do in term's of people's daily experience. If you give people free time, given the communication technology, they may still rebel against a Feudal system and put a republic in place out of preference. That's why free time should also be difficult to come by.

Perhaps you can also introduce other factors that accentuates the lack of free time. Perhaps, to make agriculture work in that post-apocalyptic world, farming is very complex -- you need recurring efforts to deal with certain side-effects from radiation, maybe add some new micro-organism that people have to work against -- while being unproductive relative to our real world.

---

And there you go, I think with some details, Feudalism can become realistic enough.

Yet at the same time, you are not restricted in having modern transportation, modern communications, modern entertainment, etc.